# System tray icon bug on Qt5.* in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, icons, tray

Subject: [QSystemTrayIcon with black background on Linux](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35832). Is there any way to solve this without recompiling Qt libs?

Comment: Couldn't you subclass the QTSystemTrayIcon class and implement the fix in that; and everywhere you were using a QTSystemTrayIcon you use your implementation?

Comment: @Petesh, you tell me. That is the question.®

Comment: It's more a case of 'what have you tried'. The sourcebase of QT seems to imply that it would be more complex than a simple subclassing in my original statement due to the separation of the public interface and private implementation.